# Why does the high capacitance of a metal oxide varistor affect sensors and signal sensitivity?

Tags: capacitor, safety, capacitance, sensitivity, varistor

I want to know why the high capacitance of metal oxide varistors affects sensors, signal sensitivity.

How does capacitance affect sensitivity ?

If we add a low capacitor in series will the total capacitance decrease so sensitivity will be better?

How does inductance affect sensitivity?

Comment: The bigger question: Why does adding capacitance between a signal wire and its return wire attenuate the high frequency portion of the signal more than the lower frequency portion. Do you know why this is true irrespective of whether the capacitance is a regular capacitor or that inside an MOV @Ahmed

Comment: Sensitivity? You mean bandwidth?

Comment: @Andy aka actually i dont know really im really interested to know

Comment: Forget about sensors and MOVs, and just understand how an RC lowpass filter works instead. You can look that up and come back to ask if you need help. And then an RC highpass filter (for what a series capacitance does). LC and LR high pass and lowpass filters should quickly fall into place after you understand RC to answer your inductance question.

Comment: The point I'm making is that you've asked a question that requires an understanding of basic principles and, if you understood those basic principles, you would have no need to ask the question. You need to do some research on the impedance of capacitors.

Comment: @DKNguyen i think thats right ,when i was reading diff between mov and tvs. So if its bandwidth why it decreases

Comment: @DKNguyen thanks for your reply , i have read again low and high pass filter , actually it gets me to the point , but actually i find big difference , where varistor doesnt have resistance to consider the case as low pass ,  but i made some simulation on protues having capacitor parallel to  pulse source , and i increase the capacitance and i found as capacitance increases the resistance to change of voltage increases until it becomes steep , and thats makes sense for sensors as they are considered as variable voltage source so capacitance should be low so it wont resist change in voltages.

Comment: @Andyaka as i commented above i found how capacitance affects variable input voltage (sensors) but  im  confused how impedance is related

Comment: A sensor output cannot be regarded as boing a voltage source. It has output resistance and this forms a low pass filter with a capacitor. If you understand this then you will see that your actual question should be deleted. If you don't understand this then you should still delete this question and ask a new question as to why capacitance can attenuate a signal.

Comment: @Andyaka oh i got it , so capacitor resist changes in voltage when it rise up or falls down leading to attenuate signal ,well i agree with u its better to ask another question , but i understand it i just didnt understand how to look it in terms of impedance can u explain it , thanks for your help .

Comment: @Andyaka  well i think i understand , capacitors has high capacitance so low impedance so it shorts for high frequency thats until self resonant frequency . And as u said sensors acts as variable voltage with resistance so i think im fully understand it , so thats why varistors are used only parallel to powet line not in signals line .

Comment: Correct, well done for getting there and realizing about self resonance.

Comment: @Andyaka thanks alot for your patience and answers , can type this as answer as i think this question might come to somebody's mind so it can help him

Comment: @Ahmedelmenshawie Yes, that is it. Sensors have their own resistance or impedance which interacts with the external capacitor.

Comment: @DKNguyen thanks for your reply it helps me alot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to know why the high capacitance of metal oxide varistors
>   affects sensors, signal sensitivity.

Basically, this question boils down to how would moderate to high capacitance affect signal levels from a sensor. And the simple answer is found in the humble RC low pass filter. It has nothing really to do with MOV varistors - any component that has significant capacitance to ground (or the return wire) can reduce the high frequency spectrum of a sensor output.

A capacitor when placed a cross an AC source will take more current when the AC source frequency is higher. This is because of the fundamental formula for a capacitor is: -

$$I = C\cdot\dfrac{dV}{dt}$$

And clearly, for the same RMS level of signals, higher frequencies have a greater value of dV/dt.

> If we add a low capacitor in series will the total capacitance
>   decrease so sensitivity will be better?

Then you will lose the main protection offered by the MOV except for very, very fast transient surges.

Comment: Thanks for your answer , adding series capacitor decreases total capacitance which varistor needs to do its job?

Comment: Anything that prevents the MOV directly connecting to the circuit it intends to protect is preventing the MOV from doing its job.

Comment: thats very useful information , so if i wanna put bypass capacitor, the capacitor  will be nearer to the power supply then varistor then load

Comment: A bypass capacitor is not a capacitor in series (with the MOV) hence it can go where you want it to go.

Comment: Oh yes u are truly right . You are so helpful . Thanks alot